# Trying to write a text wrap function but the code displays couple of blank lines after the desired output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to slice the string and then printing it on the next line.

The code works fine but it displays couple of blank lines, but according to the given for loop it should not do that

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    for i in range(0,len(string),max_width):
        print (string[i:i+max_width])    
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

```
    Input: 
    qwertyuiop
    2

    Output:
    qw
    er
    ty
    ui
    op
    None
```

Comment: or are you looking for [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `wrap` function you are not returning anything. But in your main function you are storing the output of the function in `result`. Which will have a `null` value. That's why you are getting **None** at the end of your output.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the print statement from your main code and just call the function since you already have a print in your function.